# How to pass the dropdown and text value to email subject line using Javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Need your urgent help

I have one HTML page with 2 text box, 1 dropdown and 1 button, on button click I want to open the email(as currently I am doing with javascript) with subject line as whatever is selected in the drop down and whatever is written in text box.

```
<body>
<form id='sampleform' method='post' action='' > 
   Emp Number: <input type='text' name='empnum' />  

   </p>  

   <p>  
       Unit Name: <input type='text' name='unit' />   
   </p>  
   <p>  
       Type of subscription you want:  
   <p>  
       <select name="type">  
           <option value="standard">Standard - Free</option>  
           <option value="prof">Professional - Paid</option>  
       </select>   
   </p>  
   </p>  
   <p>          
      <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' onClick="parent.location='mailto:er.saurav1@gmail.com?subject=Thanks for writing &body=Hi,%0A%0CThanks for writing. We will get back to you soon. %0A%0C%0D%0AThanks and Regards,%0A%0CSaurav Kumar%0A%0C%0A%0CFor further assistance call 81111'">
   </p> 
</form> 

</body>
```

I want when my email will open the subject line output should be:

> Emp Num | Unit Name | Selected value
>   from the drop down

Comment: Whether you can pass a subject line is *completely* dependent upon cooperation between the browser and the mail reader the user uses. It definitely is not reliable.

Comment: @Pointy: I only want to open the email when user will enter any value in text box and select any value from dropdown, I want to display all the selected and entered text in subject line of the email.

Comment: ... though actually it looks like there's an RFC for it (2468, since 1998) ...

Comment: I understand that - all I know is that I've learned that one cannot absolutely rely on the "Subject" line getting through to every possible mail client.

Comment: @Pointy: Below code I am using but its not working. Please suggest  <script language='text/javascript'>
var form = document.forms.sampleform; 
var subject = form.empnum.value + ' | ' + form.unit.value + ' | ' + form.type.value;
</script>

<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' onClick="parent.location='mailto:er.saurav1@gmail.com?subject='+ encodeURIComponent(subject) + ' &body=Hi,%0A%0CThanks for writing. We will get back to you soon. %0A%0C%0D%0AThanks and Regards,%0A%0CSaurav Kumar%0A%0C%0A%0CFor further assistance call 81111 '">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-edited the post from Srikanth Rayabhagi. Now it should work

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function sendMail(){
        var form = document.forms.sampleform;
        var empnum = form.empnum.value;
        var uname = form.unit.value;
        var ddvalue = form.type.options[form.type.selectedIndex].value;
        var subj = empnum + '|' + uname + '|' + ddvalue;
        parent.location='mailto:abc@gmail.com?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(subj) +'&body=Thanks for writing. We will get back to you soon';
    }
</script>
```

Just call sendMail() within any Button onClick event.

hth

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your `onclick`:

```
var form = document.forms.sampleform;
var subject = form.empnum.value + ' | ' + form.unit.value + ' | ' + form.type.value;
parent.location = 'mailto:er.saurav1@gmail.com?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(subject) + '&body=...';
```

Comment: I tried but its not working...<script language='text/javascript'> var form = document.forms.sampleform; var subject = form.empnum.value + ' | ' + form.unit.value + ' | ' + form.type.value;</script> <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' onClick="parent.location='mailto:er.saurav1@gmail.com?subject=' + subject + ' &body=Hi,%0A%0CThanks for writing. We will get back to you soon. %0A%0C%0D%0AThanks and Regards,%0A%0CSaurav Kumar%0A%0C%0A%0CFor further assistance call 81111'">

Comment: Please have a look, I have used encodeURIComponent also, but now on button click nothing is happening. I mean email window is not opening.

Comment: Below is the code I am using: <script language='text/javascript'>
var form = document.forms.sampleform; 
var subject = form.empnum.value + ' | ' + form.unit.value + ' | ' + form.type.value;
</script>

<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' onClick="parent.location='mailto:er.saurav1@gmail.com?subject='+ encodeURIComponent(subject) + ' &body=Hi,%0A%0CThanks for writing. We will get back to you soon. %0A%0C%0D%0AThanks and Regards,%0A%0CSaurav Kumar%0A%0C%0A%0CFor further assistance call 81111 '">

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function click_handler(){

            var x = document.forms.sampleform;
            var enum = x.empnum.value;
            var uname = x.unit.value;
            var ddvalue = x.type.options[x.type.selectedIndex].value;
            var subj = enum +'|'+uname+'|'+ddvalue;
            parent.location='mailto:abc@gmail.com?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(subj) +'&body=Thanks for writing. We will get back to you soon';

    }
</script>
<body>
<form id='sampleform' name='sampleform'> 
   Emp Number: <input type='text' name='empnum' />  

   </p>  

   <p>  

   Unit Name: <input type='text' name='unit' />  

   </p>  

    <p>  

   Type of subscription you want:  

    <p>  

    <select name="type">  

      <option value="standard">Standard - Free</option>  

      <option value="prof">Professional - Paid</option>  

    </select>  

    </p>  

  </p>  
  <p>  

<input type='button' name='Submit' value='Submit' onClick="javascript:click_handler()">
</p> 
</form> 
</body>
 </html>
```

Will be fine.. Though didn't check by running it.. Call the `click_handler_me()` on clicking the button.

Comment: Check the above one now.. I tried running the whole script.. it worked on my end.. let me know in case of any issues.